# How to pause or stop the scrolling items at the current position on mouse hover and resume on mouse leave

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, json, css-animations

I have a React page in which I am trying to display a list of items in an infinite scroll which starts at the bottom of the div and ends at the top of the div.

I am able to scroll the items circularly but I am trying to pause the scrolling effect when the mouse hovers on items but they are not stopping. They keep scrolling.

I am new to JS. Please help me to pause the items in their positions when the mouse is hovering and resume scrolling when the mouse leaves.

This is the JSON string dummy data

```js
data =  [{"item0":10},{"item1":11},{"item2":12},{"item3":13},{"item4":14},{"item5":15},{"item6":16},{"item7":17},{"item8":18},{"item9":19}];
```

**react code:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';

import "../css/dashBoard.css";


const ScrollChart = () => {

const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const alertListRef = useRef(null);
  const scrollSpeed = 1;
  const [isHovering, setIsHovering] = useState(false);
  const [shouldScroll, setShouldScroll] = useState(true);
  let scrollRef = null;
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
            //dummy data used
            const jsonStr = '[{"item0":10},{"item1":11},{"item2":12},{"item3":13},{"item4":14},{"item5":15},{"item6":16},{"item7":17},{"item8":18},{"item9":19}]';

            setData(JSON.parse(jsonStr));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error-- " + error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    let animationFrameId = null;
    let lastTimestamp = 0;
    const scrollAlerts = (timestamp) => {
      if (shouldScroll && !isHovering && alertListRef.current) {
        const scrollContainer = alertListRef.current;
        const scrollHeight = scrollContainer.scrollHeight;
        const clientHeight = scrollContainer.clientHeight;
        const scrollTop = scrollContainer.scrollTop;

        const headerHeight = document.querySelector('.alerts-header').clientHeight;
        const scrollThreshold = headerHeight;

        if (scrollTop >= scrollHeight - clientHeight - scrollThreshold) {
          // Scroll to the top and pause scrolling
          scrollContainer.scrollTop = 0;
          setShouldScroll(false);
        } else if (timestamp - lastTimestamp >= 100) {
          // Incrementally scroll by the scrollSpeed
          scrollContainer.scrollTop += scrollSpeed;
          lastTimestamp = timestamp;
        }
      }

      animationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(scrollAlerts);
    };
    const handleAnimationFrame = (timestamp) => {
    console.log("55555555555 animation recalling ");
      scrollAlerts(timestamp);
    };

    animationFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(handleAnimationFrame);

    return () => {
    console.log("6666666666 cancel animation frame");
      cancelAnimationFrame(animationFrameId);
    };
  }, [shouldScroll, isHovering]);

  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    setIsHovering(true);
    setShouldScroll(false);
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setIsHovering(false);
    setShouldScroll(true);
  };


return (
        <div className="dashboard_alertBarChart" >
           <div className="alerts-header">Alerts</div>
           <div className="alerts-container" onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}>
              <div className="alert-list" ref={alertListRef}>
                 {data.map((alert, index) => {
                     const severity = alert.severity || 'medium'; // Set default severity as 'medium' if not found
                     return (
                        <div key={index} className="alert-item">
                           <div className={`legend-box ${severity}`}></div>
                           {Object.keys(alert)[0]}: {Object.values(alert)[0]}
                        </div>
                     );
                 })}
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
   );
};
export default ScrollChart;
```

**dashBoard.css**

```
.alerts-header {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.alerts-container {
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.alert-list {
  overflow-y: auto;
  animation: scroll 20s linear infinite;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}

.alert-item {
  font-weight:bold;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  color:#09094a;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}

.legend-box {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.high {
  background-color: red;
}

.medium {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.low {
  background-color: green;
}

.dashboard_alertBarChart {
  width: 45%;
  background-color: #1eeeee1a;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 1%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**screen shot:**

[image]

This is what I tried. Help me to pause the scrolling effect when the mouse hovers on items.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using [`Element.getAnimations()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAnimations) to get the [`Animation` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation) that represents the `scroll` animation applied from CSS. You can then [`.pause()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/pause) and [`.play()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/play) as needed:

```js
const { useEffect, useState, useRef } = React;

const ScrollChart = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const alertListRef = useRef(null);
  const scrollSpeed = 1;
  const [isHovering, setIsHovering] = useState(false);
  const [shouldScroll, setShouldScroll] = useState(true);
  let scrollRef = null;
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = () => {
      try {
        //dummy data used
        const jsonStr = '[{"item0":10},{"item1":11},{"item2":12},{"item3":13},{"item4":14},{"item5":15},{"item6":16},{"item7":17},{"item8":18},{"item9":19}]';

        setData(JSON.parse(jsonStr));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error-- " + error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    setIsHovering(true);
    alertListRef.current.getAnimations()[0].pause();
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setIsHovering(false);
    alertListRef.current.getAnimations()[0].play();
  };

  return (
    <div className="dashboard_alertBarChart" >
       <div className="alerts-header">Alerts</div>
       <div className="alerts-container" onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}>
          <div className="alert-list" ref={alertListRef}>
             {data.map((alert, index) => {
               const severity = alert.severity || 'medium'; // Set default severity as 'medium' if not found
               return (
                 <div key={index} className="alert-item">
                   <div className={`legend-box ${severity}`}></div>
                   {Object.keys(alert)[0]}: {Object.values(alert)[0]}
                 </div>
               );
             })}
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
   );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<ScrollChart/>);
```

```css
.alerts-header {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.alerts-container {
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.alert-list {
  overflow-y: auto;
  animation: scroll 20s linear infinite;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}

.alert-item {
  font-weight:bold;
  padding-bottom:10px;
  color:#09094a;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}

.legend-box {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.high {
  background-color: red;
}

.medium {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.low {
  background-color: green;
}

.dashboard_alertBarChart {
  width: 45%;
  background-color: #1eeeee1a;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 1%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```